Shell sort vs Insertion sort
I did not get why shell sort is more efficient.
so here is a comparison of both algos according to what I have understood:
Insertion Sort: O(n^2) because we go through the whole array at first(kinda to divide it into sorted subarrays) and then the innerloop comes to insert the new element (the elemnt not included in the sorted subarray)
Shell Sort: does exactly what the insertion does but with some pre-work.(making it pretty much sorted) then use insertion.
So shell is basically Pro-work+Insertion. Although I know that the pre-work result in less swapping, we need anyways to go through every element when gap =1.
So why is it useful?

Shellsort is more efficient compared to other efficient sorting algos, but not in all cases. It depends on the array. See here. "Shellsort performs more operations and has higher cache miss ratio than quicksort. However, since it can be implemented using little code and does not use the call stack, some implementations of the qsort function in the C standard library targeted at embedded systems use it instead of quicksort." Wiki

"Shell Sort: does exactly what the insertion does": no it doesn't, not in the least. Have another look. Your question is founded on a fallacy.


Insertion Sort: O(n^2) because we go through the whole array at first(kinda to divide it into sorted subarrays)

Not "into sorted subarrays", but into one sorted prefix and the unsorted remainder.

Shell Sort: does exactly what the insertion does but with some pre-work.(making it pretty much sorted) then use insertion. So shell is basically Pro-work+Insertion.

The pre-work can be understood as executions of insertion sort, but on a subsequence of the array, where the indices that define that subsequence are a fixed distance apart.

Although I know that the pre-work result in less swapping, we need anyways to go through every element when gap =1. So why is it useful?

Like you say, the previous rounds (with gap > 1) will have moved several values closer to their final destination, so that less swapping is needed in the final round.
Example
Input: [4,3,2,1]
With standard insertion sort, we would need (the equivalent of) three swaps to get the least value (1) into its final position.
If we apply shell sort with a first gap of 2, then this means we do an insertion sort on subsequence [4, 2] and on subsequence [3, 1]
These two insertion sorts result in two swaps and this array:
[2,1,4,3]

It is now certain that the least value of the array is either at index 0 or index 1. So to get the least value in its final position will have a cost of at most one swap. This shows a gain: we only needed two swaps to get that least value into place.
The swaps that are performed in the "pre-work" of shell sort will on average bring values closer to their destination spots with a cost that is less than if they were moved there with a plain insertion sort, as the latter can only swap adjacent elements. Those previous rounds will not always bring values to their final spot, but on average they will bring them much closer to their final spots. The work to be done for the final round is expected to be much less than if you had to move each value from its orignal spot with only insertion sort.

thank you for your answer! another question: let us say that we have a loop that examinates every element of the array. within the loop there is an if statement, that we know will never return true to those specific elemnt of the array. In this case is it an O(n) algorithm( we basically go through every elemnt) or it is consideren O(1) (we go through elemnts but we are mainly doing nothing). If there is a difference than I can understand why less swapping ir more f$beneficial even if we go through all elemnt.

This is still O(n). Even an iteration of the loop represents some work, so that adds up to O(n). But in the last phase of shell sort, in the plain insertion sort part, the inner iteration needed to swap a value into the sorted partition will exit as soon as the value has reached its sorted value. It is not expected that this inner iteration will continue through the whole sorted partition, because of what the previous phases had already accomplished. This is a hard analysis, and it depends on the gaps that are chosen for the different shellsort phases. There is a lot on Wikipedia.
